# SQL Server : find and update column in Table 1 with Information from Table 2

Tags: sql-server, powershell, scripting

I am new to all of this and have just began scripting/programming in general. I have searched high and low and tried several things, but I have had no success. What I am trying to do

- `Table1` has `Column1`
- `Table2` has `Column2`

Within these columns are file paths. `Column1` file path will be `\\\server1\folder\video1.avi`,
`Column2` file path will be `http://server2/folder/video1.mpg`

What I am trying to do is query `Table1` with `Table2` and match the name of the file, in this case `video1`. This file name will always be different, thus will need something so it finds part of the string by itself. Once the match is made I need `Table1` to update `Column1` so that it matches exactly what is in `Table2.Column2`. When the change has been made and the rest of my program has finished running, all the data in `Table2` will be deleted, but I still need `Table1.Column1` to be changed permanently and not revert back to the old file path.

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:

Here is the filename for our database:

5149__20121030_120839.avi which will be converted to 5149__20121030_120839.mpg
At any given point in time the beginning of the filename will range from 5100 to 5999 the rest of it will change randomly. How I currently have things setup:

I am grabbing file names and saving them to a csv file. From there I am uploading this csv file into `Table2.Column2`. It is at this point in time where I am stuck on querying part of the file path to find a match in `Table1.Column1`. One a match is found I am trying to update the whole string in `Table1.Column1` to match what I have in `Table2.Column2`. After it is all said and done with I will delete `Table2.Column2`, any files that were moved, and start over the next day.

I have been searching all over and found a few things to try, but no luck as of yet. The closest I have come is this:

`UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column2
FROM Table1
FULL JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Column2 like '%' + Table1.Column1 + '%'`

Whenever I run this though, it takes `Table1.Column1` and sets everything to NULL instead of replacing what is in `Table2.Column2`. This was just a test in my lab to see if it would work, I had not even begun researching on how to match part of a string yet between two different tables.

Comment: Do you want to extract video1 from the path in Column2 in order to match the record that exists in Table1?  Does the Table1 record already exist?  What about extracting that name into another field before it is put into sql, then key off that field?

Comment: Davids, I added more info. Hopefully it helps out. Like I said I am new to all this and am trying to learn as I go along.

Comment: The issue with the UPDATE in your example is that you are comparing the full path in Column2 'http://server2/folder/video1.mpg' with part of the path (like '%' + Table1.Column1 + '%') in Column1.  Those will never match unless you extract the file name first or the full path in Column2 exists in Column1.  See my example below for a possible solution.

Comment: You will need to extract the file name either before loading to SQL, or after if you are going to match the records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information to know how much variation there is in the path and file extension in the two tables, but assuming they are constant, you could do something like this:

First I setup some mock tables and enter values

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(Column1 varchar(200),keyfield varchar(50))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(Column2 varchar(200),keyfield varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @Table1
SELECT '\\\server1\folder\video1.avi',''
UNION ALL
SELECT '\\\server1\folder\video27.avi',''

INSERT INTO @Table2
SELECT 'http://server2/folder/video1.mpg',''
UNION ALL
SELECT 'http://server2/folder/video27.mpg',''
```

Now update the tables like you may need to in order to make this work:

```
UPDATE @Table1 SET keyfield=(REPLACE(REPLACE(Column1,'\\\server1\folder\',''),'.avi',''))
UPDATE @Table2 SET keyfield=(REPLACE(REPLACE(Column2,'http://server2/folder/',''),'.mpg',''))
```

Start values in Table1

[image]

Now, I modify the values using the keyField to link the tables

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Column1=t2.Column2
FROM @Table1 t1 INNER JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t1.keyfield=t2.keyfield

SELECT * FROM @Table1
```

You will see that @Table1 now has the full path that was in @Table2

[image]

Comment: +1 : Extracting specific data into it's own derived field is certainly the way to go.  It centralises code and simplifies queries, it caches results rather than repeating calculations, it enables index use, etc, etc.

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work since yesterday, probably me being new, but I have not been able to figure out why I am getting this error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: Post your code.  It suggests you have something entered incorrectly in the statement.

Comment: davids, thanks for your help! I figured it out. This helps me tremendously moving forward.

Comment: Please make sure to mark it as answered (the check mark) so others will know which solution helped.

Comment: davids, I have modified a piece of the file path and now my tables are not updating. I now have file paths that look like this: 'UPDATE Table1 SET keyfield=(REPLACE(REPLACE(Column1,'http://server1/folder/',''),'.avi',''))
UPDATE Table2 SET keyfield=(REPLACE(REPLACE(Column2,'http://server2/folder/',''),'.mpg',''))' When I ran this as a file path it worked perfectly, but now that both are URLs Column1 does not update and match Colum2. Any ideas to try?

Comment: I see that you have added ; to the statement ".avi','';" .  Was that on purpose?  If that doesn't fix it, you may need to post your full code.

Comment: Still haven't gotten used to looking for the little details yet. I had been starring at that for awhile and just did not see it. Thanks again!

Comment: davids, quick question. How do I turn this:    UPDATE Table1 SET keyfield=(REPLACE(REPLACE(Column1,'\\\server1\folder\',''),'.avi','')) Into this    UPDATE Table1 SET keyfield=(REPLACE(REPLACE(Column1,'\\\*\folder\',''),'.avi','')) ? Make Server1 a wildcard, the IP changes from time to time and I want to replace them all without having to edit anything. Thanks!

Comment: % is the wild card in SQL but I have never used it in a REPLACE statement.  If the change is only occasional and the wild card doesn't work, change it manually.  If that won't work, ask another question as it is a different topic and perhaps someone else will know a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty ugly query to consider the file path variation, and may not be optimized, but for a one-time run and to get it all in one script:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column2 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 
    ON substring(Table2.Column2, 
                len(Table2.Column2) - CASE charindex('\', reverse(rtrim(Table2.Column2))) WHEN 0 THEN charindex('/', reverse(rtrim(Table2.Column2))) ELSE charindex('\', reverse(rtrim(Table2.Column2))) END + 2, 
                charindex('.', Table2.Column2) - len(Table2.Column2) + CASE charindex('\', reverse(rtrim(Table2.Column2))) WHEN 0 THEN charindex('/', reverse(rtrim(Table2.Column2))) ELSE charindex('\', reverse(rtrim(Table2.Column2))) END - 2 
        )
        = 
        substring(Table1.Column1, 
                len(Table1.Column1) - CASE charindex('\', reverse(rtrim(Table1.Column1))) WHEN 0 THEN charindex('/', reverse(rtrim(Table1.Column1))) ELSE charindex('\', reverse(rtrim(Table1.Column1))) END + 2, 
                charindex('.', Table1.Column1) - len(Table1.Column1) +CASE charindex('\', reverse(rtrim(Table1.Column1))) WHEN 0 THEN charindex('/', reverse(rtrim(Table1.Column1))) ELSE charindex('\', reverse(rtrim(Table1.Column1))) END - 2 
        )
```